# When someone is blocked from chat, is that an SE-chat wide block?

Tags: support, chat

I was recently blocked from chat (I deserve that anyway). Anyway, I thought this block will stop me from chatting anywhere in SE, but for some reason I am able to in some rooms [like this SO room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22362124#22362124), but not in some other rooms.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: They let any old rabble in the Lounge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not yourself.  That is, [you](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/39565/menotalk) on Chat.SE is not [you](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3177651/menotalk) on Chat.SO (or [you](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/248595/menotalk) on Chat.Meta.SE).  Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, and Meta Stack Exchange have their own chat domains, rooms, and users, so there's 3 separate accounts.  You're not suspended on Chat.SO or Chat.M.SE, but you are on Chat.SE.

Comment: Curious to know if it's even possible for a mod or even SE-employee to give real cross-network chat suspension, i.e. on all three domains.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not for mods (chat.meta only has employees as diamonds, if nothing else), but for CMs and Q&A devs, why wouldn't it be? Worst case, we'd have to go to three domains and issue three suspensions. Not hard.

Comment: @Anna sure, meant more like "is it possible with one click" :)